# How are const variables created in Objective-C Classes?

Tags: objective-c, macos, oop, class, object

Are they given assigned a value the moment they are declared (the interface) or are they assigned a value in the constructor of the class (the implementation)? If possible please give a brief example of how constant variables are assigned values in classes.

Comment: What do you mean by constant variables in Obj-C classes?

Comment: Constant Member data. i.e.  const int variable in class theClass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C does not support const instance variables.  All instances variables are initialized to zero or nil when the class is instantiated.